# XSLT 2.0 flexible with default or different prefixed namespace of the same URI

Tags: xslt-2.0, xml-namespaces

I am new to XSLT and am stumbling on some boiler plate namespace handling.

I have the following xslt where the goal is to simply rename one element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1/xml/" >
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- element template that copies over elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- attribute template to copy attributes over -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- "other" template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Rename an element -->
    <xsl:template match="BOPPolicyQuoteInqRq/RqUID" >
        <xsl:element name="RqUUID">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transforming the following xml works as expected:

```
<ACORD xmlns="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1/xml/">
  <InsuranceSvcRq>
    <BOPPolicyQuoteInqRq>
      <RqUID>E2BA6308-62D5-43AC-B8C1-7616FDFE9C98</RqUID>    
    </BOPPolicyQuoteInqRq>
  </InsuranceSvcRq>
</ACORD>
```

However, this semantically equivalent xml fails:

```
<bloat:ACORD xmlns:bloat="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1/xml/">
  <bloat:InsuranceSvcRq>
    <bloat:BOPPolicyQuoteInqRq>
      <bloat:RqUID>E2BA6308-62D5-43AC-B8C1-7616FDFE9C98</bloat:RqUID>    
    </bloat:BOPPolicyQuoteInqRq>
  </bloat:InsuranceSvcRq>
</bloat:ACORD>
```

The error i receive is:

```
Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Undeclared prefix in element name: bloat
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ComputedElement.getElementName(ComputedElement.java:429)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:388)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:371)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:239)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1056)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.TextOnlyCopyRuleSet.process(TextOnlyCopyRuleSet.java:65)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1044)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:2088)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1911)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XsltBuilder.process(XsltBuilder.java:141)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.component.xslt.XsltEndpoint.onExchange(XsltEndpoint.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:71)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:141)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProducer.process(UnitOfWorkProducer.java:68)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:412)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:380)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:270)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:380)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:221)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:124)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:137)
    ... 32 more
```

It appears even though these xmls are semantically equivalent as far as the xml spec would be concerned, the XSLT transformer is getting hung up because one declares a prefix and the other doesn't (i would also venture to say it will get hung up if one was prefixed with 'foo' and one with 'bar').

I am in a position where I can't force the client who's passing me xml to declare a specific prefix or namespace a certain way. I also can't guarantee they won't decide to utilize a different prefix alias tomorrow.

My understanding of declaring the `xpath-default-namespace` attribute was that it told the xslt transformer what namespace URI the entire document will be associated with regardless of whether it would be declared as a default prefix, a prefix with the alias 'bloat', or even a prefix with the alias 'rainbowunicorns'.

What precisely does the attribute `xpath-default-namespace` do and how can I can write a flexible XSLT that can gracefully handle any amount of semantically equivalent namespaces regardless of what flavor of namespace declaration the client decides?

Specs if relevant:
Camel 2.16.2
Saxon-HE 9.5.1-8

Updated transform that works with both xmls (courtesy of Martin Honnen):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1/xml/" >
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- element template that copies over elements -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- "other" template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Rename an element -->
    <xsl:template match="BOPPolicyQuoteInqRq/RqUID" >
        <xsl:element name="RqUUID" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- attribute template to copy attributes over -->
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

by

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

as that way you copy any namespaces in scope as well and then use

```
<xsl:template match="BOPPolicyQuoteInqRq/RqUID" >
    <xsl:element name="{QName(namespace-uri(), if (prefix-from-QName(node-name(.))) then concat(prefix-from-QName(node-name(.)),':', 'RqUUID') else 'RqUUID')}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

With some variables to keep the code readable the whole stylesheet becomes

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1/xml/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="BOPPolicyQuoteInqRq/RqUID">
        <xsl:variable name="new-local-name" as="xs:string" select="'RqUUID'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="prefix-from-QName(node-name(.))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="new-name" as="xs:string" select="if ($prefix) then concat($prefix,':', $new-local-name) else $new-local-name"/>
        <xsl:element name="{QName(namespace-uri(), $new-name)}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: This code definitely works, would you be willing to provide an explanation as to why each of the changes you suggested ended up working? Sidenote: I did also have to remove the | text() portion of my "other" rule as coupled with these changes it made an ambiguous rule set (the xslt transformer gave a really go error that helped me fix it myself). Just want to learn the _why_

Comment: Thinking about it again, the suggestion above will obviously fail with a default namespace in the input as then the constructed name would be `:RqUUID`. I will need to try and check how to write code that works with both types of input.

Comment: As for an explanation, basically if you want to copy nodes unchanged then it is common practice to start with the template I suggested first instead of the two (respectively three, I had overlooked the third) you tried, it is a more compact way and the `xsl:copy` will copy any in-scope namespace while your attempts with `xsl:element` don't do that.

Comment: The `xpath-default-namespace` is only for XPath selection and pattern matching, not for output serialization. So you have to copy the namespace when using `xsl:element`, using the `namespace` attribute.

Comment: This might seem odd but your first transform did work on both test cases from my side. I'll post an edit to the question containing what transform seems to be currently working. Then I'll look at what you have and try to learn a lot more from it. Thank you so much for your explanations and prompt responses.

Answer (score 1):

First a word on diagnostics: it doesn't make much sense to print a Java stack trace when you get a dynamic error in your stylesheet. Saxon reports the error to the registered ErrorListener, and the standard ErrorListener produces diagnostics that are designed to be useful to the stylesheet author, telling you where in the XSLT the failure occurred, and an XSLT-level stack trace showing where that code was called from. If you're not seeing these diagnostics then you're doing something wrong.

Second, why did it fail? You are doing

```
<xsl:element name="{name()}">
```

and the value of name() is something like `bloat:RqUID`. The rules for xsl:element say:

> [ERR XTDE0830] In the case of an xsl:element instruction with no
>   namespace attribute, it is a non-recoverable dynamic error if the
>   effective value of the name attribute is a QName whose prefix is not
>   declared in an in-scope namespace declaration for the xsl:element
>   instruction.

If you want to copy the name unchanged, use `<xsl:copy>`, or if you prefer, `<xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">`

Comment: Wow never expected to get an answer from the author of the book I bought twice (dog literally ate the cover of my first one). Diagnostics: I do see more detailed information on the stack trace including the line and column it failed on in the xslt, the unrecognized character, etc. However, this tends to be compile time errors versus runtime. It sounds like I'm doing something wrong. Any suggestions you can point me towards for getting better runtime diagnostics next time would be appreciated. This may be a camel thing too as we are leveraging camel for it's useful integration framework.

Comment: Also thank you for the description of the error in my identity rule. I see now that utilizing xsl:element in this case was an ill choice compared to xsl:copy since retaining original namespace prefixes (if any) is desired. I'm being forced to hunt and peck around in the book instead of reading front to back (my preference) due to project timeline pressures. When I get the time to sit down and read for comprehension instead of deliver a timeline I won't have such noobish questions :)